# MVC Creating a PDF file for one table row

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, itext

I have a problem with adding a button that will generate a PDF file for a specific table row. I can do this for whole table but not for a specific row.

My "Execute" view (create PDF file for entire table):

```
<div id="Grid">
            <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="ExeTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center">Order nr</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Mat nr</th>
                        <th class="text-center">SAP nr</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Batch nr</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Tank</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="myTable">
                    @foreach (var item in Model.ib)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td class="text-center">@item.OrderNr</td>
                            <td class="text-center">@item.MatNr</td>
                            <td class="text-center">@item.SapNr</td>
                            <td class="text-center">@item.BatchNr</td>
                            <td class="text-center">@item.TankName</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Export", "Order", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <input type="hidden" name="GridHtml" />
            <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Export" />
        }


    <script>
        $(function (print) {
            $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
                $("input[name='GridHtml']").val($("#Grid").html());
            });
        });
    </script>
```

But I want to have a new column in the table where there will be a button to generate a PDF for a specific row. I tried something but without success.

```
// I tried this
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="ExeTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Create PDF</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Order nr</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Mat nr</th>
                        <th class="text-center">SAP nr</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Batch nr</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Tank</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="myTable">
                    @foreach (var item in Model.ib)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td class="text-center">
                                @using (Html.BeginForm("Export", "Order", FormMethod.Post))
                                {
                                    <input type="hidden" name="GridHtml" />
                                    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Export" />
                                }
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-center">@item.OrderNr</td>
                            <td class="text-center">@item.MatNr</td>
                            <td class="text-center">@item.SapNr</td>
                            <td class="text-center">@item.BatchNr</td>
                            <td class="text-center">@item.TankName</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

My method that generete PDF file in "Order" controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateInput(false)]
        public FileResult Export(string GridHtml)
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                StringReader sr = new StringReader(GridHtml);
                Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream);
                pdfDoc.Open();
                XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr);
                pdfDoc.Close();
                return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/pdf", "Grid.pdf");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initial example pulls the inner contents of the `Grid` element. There does not appear to be a surrounding identifiable element from which to pull the contents for a row. A simple fix would be to add an `id` to each row, change the button id to a class to add the eventlistener, and add a `data-` attribute to hold info on which row was clicked:

```html
@foreach (var item in Model.ib)
{
    <tr id="@item.OrdrNr">
        <td class="text-center">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Export", "Order", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <input type="hidden" name="GridHtml" />
                <input type="submit" class="btnSubmit" data-row="#@item.OrdeNr" value="Export" />
            }
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">@item.OrderNr</td>
        <td class="text-center">@item.MatNr</td>
        <td class="text-center">@item.SapNr</td>
        <td class="text-center">@item.BatchNr</td>
        <td class="text-center">@item.TankName</td>
    </tr>
}
```

And the JavaScript:

```js
$(".btnSubmit").click(function (event) {
    var target = $(event.currentTarget).data('row');
    $("input[name='GridHtml']").val($(target).html());
});
```

What this will send to your Controller is just the contents of the clicked row:

```html
<td class="text-center">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Export", "Order", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <input type="hidden" name="GridHtml" />
        <input type="submit" class="btnSubmit" data-row="#@item.OrdeNr" value="Export" />
    }
</td>
<td class="text-center">@item.OrderNr</td>
<td class="text-center">@item.MatNr</td>
<td class="text-center">@item.SapNr</td>
<td class="text-center">@item.BatchNr</td>
<td class="text-center">@item.TankName</td>
```

In the controller, you can remove the button, wrap that in the rest of your table tags, and then convert to PDF.